# How check type reference - dart

Tags: dart

If I have a object like this:

```
class MyClass<K>{...
```

How I could check type of K? If was a variable was easy,
ex:

```
(myVar is Object)... //true | false
```

But in my case, this dont works:

```
(K is Object) // awalys false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `==` here. Using `is` is for comparing the type of variable, not a literal type.

This will only check if `K` is actually `Object` if you use `K == Object`. If you pass `K` as `int` for instance, it will not be considered to be an `Object`.

Comment: Not like I hadn't thought of that before hehe

Answer (score 0):

I recommend *not* using `==` for comparison of `Type` objects. It only checks exact equality, which might be useful in a few situations, but in plenty of situations you do want a subtype check.

You can get that subtype check using a helper function like:

```dart
bool isSubtype<S, T>() => <S>[] is List<T>;
```

Then you can check either `isSubtype<K, Object>` to check if `K` is a subtype of `Object` (which is true for everything except `Null` and types equivalent to `Object?`, but that can also be checked like `null is! K`), or `isSubtype<Object, K>` to check whether `K` is a supertype of `Object`.

It has the advantage that you can compare to any type, not just types you can write literals for. For example `K == List` only works for `List<dynamic>`. If you need to check whether `K` is a `List<int>`, you can do `isSubtype<K, List<int>>`.

You can get equivalence of types (mutual subtype), without requiring them to be the *same* type, by doing `isSubtype` in both directions. For example `isSubtype<Object?, dynamic>()` and `isSubtype<dynamic, Object?>()` are both true, but if `K` is `Object?` then `K == dynamic` is false.